# What will a function return if there's no explicit 'return'

Tags: c, function, return, undefined-behavior

I bumped into this problem when I forgot to write the `return` clause of a function, but there was no warning or error in `gcc`. I fixed it but started wondering why the function would return something *meaningless* without a `return`. Here are some examples I tried:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int func1 () {
        int i;
        i = 2;
}

int func2 (int a) {
        int i = a+3;
}

int func3 () {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++);
}

int main(void) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        a = func1();
        printf("a = %d \n", a);
        b = func2(a);
        printf("b = %d \n", b);
        c = func3();
        printf("c = %d \n", c);
}
```

And the results are:

```
a = 1 
b = 4 
c = 7
```

My questions:

1) why these results? Is there any general rule for this?
2) why keep this thing rather than report an error? Can it be somehow 'useful' somewhere?

Comment: Good question. I'm particularly interested in if anyone has an answer to your question why - if it's not well defined - it's still not an error to do so.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Isn't `return;` perfectly valid?

Comment: If compiled in Visual Studio 2008 and later, compiler gives error `func must return a value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and will depend on the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) being used. If the caller is expecting the result in a register then whatever value was last in the register will be used.

**Edit**

The [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `6.9.1` *Function definitions* paragraph *12* says:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

`clang` will warn by default and `gcc` will warn with `-Wall`, in general you should enable warnings.

Comment: And not just the calling convention, for example the last value of eax on x86. Very undefined indeed.

Answer (score 8):

It is undefined behaviour per section 6.9.1, paragraph 12 (of the N1570 draft of the C standard):

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

The behaviour is not undefined if the return value is not used by the caller.

There is no diagnostic message required for mere undefined behaviour, so the compiler is not obliged to warn. gcc will warn if you ask it to (`-Wreturn-type`, implied by `-Wall`), and clang warns by default.

For functions returning a type other than `void`, a `return` statement must include an expression whose value shall be returned, per 6.8.6.4, paragraph 1:

> A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is void. A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is void.

Comment: Is **return;** a valid return statement?

Comment: Not if the function is declared to return something other than `void`.

Comment: `6.9.1, paragraph 12` where is this from ??

Comment: @DanielFischer I had the idea that in functions returning void we are not supposed to use `return` in any way.Should I use `return;` for such functions henceforth?

Comment: @DanielFischer Is not using `return;` for functions returning void UB?

Comment: @mf_ this is from the C standard

Comment: @Thokchom, why should it be? As you can see from the explanation, it would only be UB if an attempt would be made to use a return value. A caller of a `void` function will never attempt this.

Comment: @Thokchom No, if the function doesn't return anything, the return value cannot be used anyway, so reaching the terminating `}` is well-defined behaviour then.

Comment: @DanielFischer So the statement `return;` has no use anywhere in C?As it can't be used in a function returning void, or in functions that expect a return other than void?

Comment: @Thokchom It's useful in `void` functions to return at some point if a condition is met, `if (we_are_done) return; do_something_more();`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh,so when we want to "move out of" that function when a condition is met eh?

Comment: @Thokchom Yes, similar to a `break;` statement.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you,else I would have surely ended up using **return;** in all functions.

Answer (score 2):

On my system (gcc 4.5.3, linux), compiling your code with no optimization, I get this:

```
main:
...
    call    func1
    movl    %eax, 28(%esp)
...
```

i.e. the return value of `func1` is drawn from the eax register, but that register is never set within `func1`, so the return value is whatever happened to be in that register when the function was called.